# Django complains that query must be used in subquery, when it is being used in a subquery

Tags: python, django

I have the following custom `QuerySet` method for a model called `Program`:

```
def with_volunteer_stats(self):
    from programs.models import Session
    volunteers_needed = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('num_student_seats') / F('student_volunteer_ratio'),
        output_field=models.IntegerField())

    sessions = (
        Session.objects.filter(program_id=OuterRef('pk'))
        .annotate(num_volunteers=Count('volunteer_attendances__volunteer', distinct=True))
        .order_by('num_volunteers')
    )
    qs = self.annotate(
        volunteers_needed=volunteers_needed,
        least_volunteers=Subquery(sessions.values('num_volunteers')[0])
    ).annotate(
        remaining_volunteers_needed=(F('volunteers_needed') - F('num_volunteers'))
    )
    return qs
```

When running this, I get the exception:

`ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

The traceback shows the exception occurring on the evaluation of the line using `Subquery`. This is very close to the example in the Django documentation on how to use `Subquery`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.  Now that I have a better idea what's happening, I thought I'd add an explanation for posterity.

The problem appears to be here:

```
Subquery(sessions.values('num_volunteers')[0])
#                                         ^^^
```

The intent is that Subquery is being given a QuerySet, but what's actually happening is that the item accessor is forcing evaluation prematurely.  In other words, this yields a QuerySet:

```
sessions.values('num_volunteers')
```

But this forces evaluation to yield an object:

```
sessions.values('num_volunteers')[0]
```

This means the `sessions.values('num_volunteers')` QuerySet is evaluated outside of the context of the Subquery.  So the error message is correct, if unclear.

Per mfrackowiak's comment below, the Django documentation offers a recommendation for how to [limit the subquery to a single row](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#limiting-the-subquery-to-a-single-row):

```
sessions.values('num_volunteers')[:1]
```

Comment: Might be worth noting - looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to achieve the desired effect `[:1]` should be used instead of `[0]`.